# Encryption process working half

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char inpusr[100];
int i, length,key;
length=100;
scanf("%[^\n]s",inpusr);
scanf("%d",&key);
printf("%s\n", inpusr);
    for(i = 0; i <=length; i++) {
        if(inpusr[i] >= 97 && inpusr[i] <=122) {
            inpusr[i] = inpusr[i] + key;
            if (inpusr[i]>122){
             inpusr[i] = (inpusr[i] - 122)+96;

            }
        }

    }
printf("%s\n", inpusr);
return 0;
}
```

I wrote a program in C to encrypt a string in Caesar cipher method but why my code isn't being able to show shifted alphabets when input is 'z' and key is above 6.

Comment: Unless you end your first input with an `'s'` your code will not work at all. The `'s'` is *not* part of the `"%["` format. See e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more information.

Comment: Now is also a perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Lastly, there are also a few other problems. Like you going out of bounds of your array `inpusr`, as well as you going beyond the string terminator and into uninitialized (and indeterminate) parts of the array. Also don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by `96` you mean the [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) character `'\`'` then say so.

Comment: Thank u alot ... It really helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, follow some guides on how to manipulate char arrays.
Char arrays are not Strings.

```
char inpusr[100];
scanf("%[^\n]s",inpusr);
```

If you type here "Hello" do you know what you get inside the array?
[H e l l o \0 \0 \0 \0 \0 %^j .....]
next time you could use

```
#include <string.h>
memset( inpusr , 0 , sizeof(inpusr));
```

Now regarding your code you say

```
if(a>10 && a<100)
{
    if (a<5) // This is a logic error.If a<10 you don't get in to block.
    {
    }
}
```

Out of interest Caesar Cipher Method, is A=(x+n) modulo 26.

This is a working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char inpusr[100];
int i, length,key;
length=100;
memset( inpusr , 0 , sizeof(inpusr));
scanf("%[^\n]s",inpusr);
scanf("%d",&key);
printf("%s\n", inpusr);
for(i = 0; i <=length; i++)
{
    if(inpusr[i] >= 97 && inpusr[i] <=122)
    {
        inpusr[i] = (((inpusr[i] - 97 + key) % 26) + 97);
    }
    else if ((inpusr[i] >= 65 && inpusr[i] <=90))
    {
        inpusr[i] = (((inpusr[i] - 65 + key) % 26) + 65);
    }

}
printf("%s\n", inpusr);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you alot ... That really helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that when you calculate the encrypted value of each character you might encounter values greater than 127, which will cause overflow in the calculation and lead to a negative value of `inpuser[i]`.

As an example, if `inpusr[i]` is 122 ('z') and key is 6, then the new value of `inpuser[i]` will be -128 and not 128 (which is needed for the calculation to be correct).

One way of fixing this is to reimplement the calculation of the encoded character with a temporary `int` variable, which will remove the overflow condition.

```
int main()
{
char inpusr[100];
int i, length,key;
length=100;
scanf("%[^\n]s",inpusr);
scanf("%d",&key);
printf("%s\n", inpusr);
    for(i = 0; i <=length; i++) {
        if(inpusr[i] >= 97 && inpusr[i] <=122) {
            int encoded_char;
            encoded_char = inpusr[i] + key;
            if (encoded_char>122){
             encoded_char = (encoded_char - 122)+96;

        }
        inpusr[i] = encoded_char;
    }

}
printf("%s\n", inpusr);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Caesar cipher**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char inpusr[100];
    char key_input[3];
    int key = 0;
    int len = 100;

    fgets(inpusr, len, stdin);
    printf("%s\n", inpusr);
    fgets(key_input, 3, stdin); // to allow -25
    key = atoi(key_input);
    printf("%d\n", key);
    while (len--)
    {
        if (inpusr[len] >= 97 && inpusr[len] <=122)
            inpusr[len] = (inpusr[len] - 97 + (key % 26) + 26) % 26 + 97; // '+ 26' is added in case of negative key
    }
    printf("%s\n", inpusr);
    return 0;
}
```

Avoid scanf since it is unsafe (you can exploit bufferoverflow).

Also you don't account for uppercase letters.

Sorry if I forgot anything.